# Как осуществить движение по вектору в Unity2D?

Tags: c#, vector, move, unity3d

Делаю игру с видом сверху. Когда нажимаю стрелку вправо, моделька начинает вращаться вправо находясь при этом на своем месте. Когда нажимаю на стрелку влево - аналогично, только вращение происходит в левую сторону. Когда отпускаю моделька перестает вращаться. При этом у модельки (самолета, в данном случае) есть носовая часть, т.е. когда я отпускаю кнопку вращения, нос самолета может смотреть куда угодно.

**Вопрос:** Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать чтобы на кнопку *стрелка вверх* самолет начал движение исходя из того в какую сторону повернута его носовая часть? Надеюсь, правильно объяснил :) Вот код.

```
//выше только объявление переменных
    private void Start()
{
    _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    _animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    _spriteRenderer = GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>();
}

private void Update()
{
    Move();
}

private void Move()
{
    Vector2 direction = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
    _moveVelocity = direction.normalized * Speed;

    if (direction.x < 0.0F)
    {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * SpeedOfTurn);
    }

    if (direction.x > 0.0F)
    {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.back * SpeedOfTurn);
    }
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        //т.е. на данный момент он летит просто вверх не зависимо от того куда смотрит сама моделька самолета
        _rigidbody.MovePosition(_rigidbody.position + _moveVelocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание на эту строчку:

```
Vector2 direction = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
```

Вы рассчитываете *direction* на основании нажатых стрелочек.
Соответственно, когда стрелки поворота нажаты вы можете управлять кораблём. В этом легко убедится, нажав одновременно вбок и вверх или выведя *direction* в консоль:

```
Debug.Log(direction);
```

Вместо этого стоит рассчитывать направление движения на основании z-координаты вашего *GameObject*.
Это можно сделать следующим образом. Во-первых в методе Start сохранить изначальный поворот в поле класса *startRotationZ*

```
 startRotationZ = 360 - transform.eulerAngles.z; //Если ваша модель будет лететь задом/боком измените число 360
```

А затем, в методе *Move* каждый раз обновлять текущий поворот и текущее направление движения.

```
 var currentRotationZinRadians = (transform.eulerAngles.z + startRotationZ) * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
 var currentDirection = new Vector2(Mathf.Cos(currentRotationZinRadians), Mathf.Sin(currentRotationZinRadians));
 _moveVelocity = сurrentDirection * Speed;
```

PS: а ещё, если в `transform.Rotate` добавить умножение на Time.DeltaTime ваш поворот станет плавным и вы получите поведение, похожее на полет самолета в 2D.